# Executar função se a input conter certo texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    if ($fa.ismod = true) {
        if (document.getElementById("input#message").value = "/msg") {
            alert('tudo okay');
        }
    }
});
```

Esse código deveria fazer um alert se a input#message contesse o texto /msg porem ele retorna isto:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)

Comment: O seletor de getElementById está incorreto e na condição `if` você está atribuindo o valor "/msg" não comparando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro apresentando ocorreu por que você tentou atribuir `value` para um elemento que não existe.

Desta forma validará o valor do elemento HTML que possua o `id` igual `message`.

```
if (document.getElementById("message").value === "/msg") {
    alert('tudo okay');
}
```

Desta forma validará o elemento `input` HTML que possua o `id` igual a `message`.

```
if ($("input#message").val() === "/msg") {
    alert('tudo okay');
}
```

Note os erros que apontei por comentário.

Comment: obrigado! :D ^^